# css: animate border on hover

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create menu with border (see http://multijuice.org/), and I need to move border on hover from active element to `hover`ed. How I can do this? Maybe, anybody know some tutorials?

**UPD:** Done! See [this js file](http://multijuice.org/menuhover.js) for answer. Thanks all!

Comment: Very common question, but i'l still ask back. *What have you tried?*

Comment: @Ravi good comment. I would like to add that if you have not tried CSS transitions to your :hover, try them. Otherwise please post the code that you are trying so that we can help further.

Comment: is this what u want? http://jsfiddle.net/CristiKavi/5qw4u32y/1/

Comment: @RaviDhoriyaツ I've tried to move `border-bottom`, but it's don't work for me - I don't know how to move `border` to element with class `active` with animation.

Comment: @Kavya no, I want to move `border-bottom` from `active` element to `:hover` element with animation.

Comment: May be you could use pseudo border using a div. Then you can move/animate the div whatever you want with js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/gujrud4y/

You can use something like this but you need to change the position of underlined on every page or you can use jQuery to check which `<li>` has active class and set accordingly

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0px;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 0;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span.border {
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .5s linear;
}
li:nth-child(1):hover ~ span.border {
  left: 0px;
}
li:nth-child(2):hover ~ span.border {
  left: 80px;
}
li:nth-child(3):hover ~ span.border {
  left: 160px;
}
li:nth-child(4):hover ~ span.border {
  left: 240px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li class="active">two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <span class="border"></span>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks! but what I'm doing wrong? `:hover` event doesn't work. please, see [that link](http://multijuice.org/)

Comment: add a width for `<li>` and the `span` should be under `ul`

Comment: I can't add span under ul, 'couse it's automatically generated by wordpress.

Comment: ok so you will need to use jquery

Comment: How rude @KirillDanshin! You could have mentioned earlier about Wordpress. It would have save lot of time of answer posters. In this case effort of Vitorino isn't useful for you (unless you customize WP manually). Plz consider asking more detailed question next time, add proper tags.

Comment: @RaviDhoriyaツ okey, thanks. please, see the link again, I'm writing js script, but it's very glitch now. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this css class in your code :

Changes this

```
#main-nav .current-menu-item a, #main-nav .current_page_item a, .selected{
     border-bottom: 3px solid #f5503b;
     padding-bottom: 72px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;
}
```

to

```
#main-nav .current-menu-item a, #main-nav .current_page_item a, .selected, #main-nav li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f5503b;
}
```

And give the `padding` to the class `.#main-nav li a` like this :

```
#main-nav li a {
   border: 0 none;
   color: #111;
   display: block;
   height: 36px;
   line-height: 36px;
   margin: 0 10px;
   padding-bottom: 72px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: ok, but you it don't give me answer to my question.